# CoordinatorLayout add padding between elements

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button, floating-action-menu

I want to have two FloatingActionButtons in my CoordinatorView. But when I try to add margin to the top FloatingActionButton, It applies from end of the view - It should add space between FloatingActionButtons.
XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/wordpackAddButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/add"
    app:elevation="5dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/wordpacks_list"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/importWordpack"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/add"
    app:elevation="5dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/wordpackAddButton"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/wordpacks_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: So how does it look when you add `android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"` to the second FAB?

Comment: @EugenPechanec Thats the problem. FAB looks exactly the same. But when I add marginBottom="200dp", its applied from the right bottom of the CoordinatorView

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1:**

Add another `View` to make a `gap` between two `FAB's`. Set the `anchor` of `View` to `top` position of the `wordpackAddButton` and set the anchor of `importWordpack` to `top-right` position of the `View`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/wordpacks_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/wordpackAddButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/add"
        app:elevation="5dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/wordpacks_list"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/gap"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/wordpackAddButton"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top">

    </View>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/importWordpack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:src="@drawable/add"
        app:elevation="5dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/gap"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

Wrap two `FAB` into a `LinearLayout` and `anchor` this layout to the `bottom-right` position of `ListView`.

**Here is an workaround:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/wordpacks_list"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clipToPadding="false">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/importWordpack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/add"
            app:elevation="5dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/wordpackAddButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/add"
            app:elevation="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/wordpacks_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: You'll have to use padding instead of margin and `android:clipToPadding="false"` so the shadows are drawn correctly. Still before Lollipop the inset will be greater beacuse of compat shadow, and because FABs are not direct children of CoordinatorLayout they won't play well with Snackbars (move out of the way).

Answer (score 1):

Add this view after Fab button and change top level fab's 
layout_anchor to transparent_view.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="8dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/wordpackAddButton"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top"
    app:useCompatPadding="false"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:id="@+id/transparent_view"
    android:layout_height="8dp"/>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar problem while implementing a FAB Menu. 
You can solve this problem by wrapping the second FAB in a `FrameLayout` like so:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/wordpackAddButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:elevation="5dp"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="56dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/wordpackAddButton"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right">
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/importWordpack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:elevation="5dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/wordpackAddButton" />
</FrameLayout>
```

This might be a bit of a hacky solution but it is simple and it works. The `padding` value of the `FrameLayout` is set to 56dp since that is the size of the FAB.

Comment: That'll mess up padding below Lollipop. FAB has to be direct child of CoordinatorLayout so it correctly subtracts extra space occupied by compat shadow and positions the FAB.

Comment: Wow thanks for clarifying I did not know that! So the only way (which would even be more hacky) would be putting a View between those FABs?